# Plugin com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:4.6.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:

Tags: soapui

I am using Soap UI 5.0 open source  version to test REST services. I was running my SoapUI test cases  via maven using Soap UI maven plug-in 4.6.1 and it was running without error.
But now, I am experiencing issue in running the same test cases. Following is the error:

[ERROR] Plugin com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:4.6.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:jar:4.6.1 in nexus(http://*******:8380/nexus/content/groups/public)

Here is my setting on POM xml

```
<pluginRepository>
<id>SmartBearPluginRepository</id>
<url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
</pluginRepository>
<plugin>                                                                                                           
<groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
<artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>4.6.1</version>                                                       
<inherited>false</inherited>                                                             
<configuration>                                                                
<junitReport>true</junitReport>                                                            
<exportAll>true</exportAll>                                                            
<outputFolder>target/surefire-reports</outputFolder>                                                             
<printReport>true</printReport>                                                            
<testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>                                                            
</configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
<phase>test</phase>
<goals>
<goal>test</goal>
</goals>                                                                            
<configuration>                                                                    
<projectFile>${basedir}/<DIR>/Project.xml</projectFile>                                                               
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

I manually copied the plug-in jars and POM into local maven repository but no luck.

Could you please advise what could be the issue ?
Do I need to update my Maven Setting.xml ???
Is Soap UI maven plug-in 4.6.1 has been restricted for non-license users ?

Comment: try `mvn -X com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:test` to see if that helps

Comment: The issue has been fixed now.I have added a proxy repository in internal nexus repository following steps here http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config-sect-new-repo.html. The proxy repository should be created with the artifact ID name(soapui-maven-plugin) as used in POM.
aslo,Delete smartbear folder if it's available under .m2 repository